# How to handle toggle event on other close button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, togglebutton

I have created toggle effect using jquery. I want to close a popup div with top-right close button, without affecting current toggle effect.

for the demo see the link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".infoBtn").click(function(){
           $(".popUpDiv").toggle("fast");
           //$(this).toggleClass("active");
           return false;
     });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm3sC/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Use:   `$(".infoBtn, .closePopsUp").click(function(){`

Answer (score 1):

use multiple selector on click event

```
    $(".infoBtn,.closePopsUp").click(function(){
    $(".popUpDiv").toggle("fast");

    return false;
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Rm3sC/6/)

Comment: i was working in the fiddle and by the time i posted this .. the post already had an answer.. :(..anyways giving you +1 ..that was fast.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple selectors in your selector string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".infoBtn, .closePopsUp").click(function(){
           $(".popUpDiv").toggle("fast", function(){
               //animation complete
               $(this).toggleClass("active");
           });
           return false;
     });
});
```

I also added in functionality to toggle the class after the animation is complete. This is a good practice as it ensures that any CSS rules applied to this class do not affect the animation.

**Source(s)**

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

If can do the same in click event of `#closePopsPan`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $(".infoBtn").click(function(){
                    $(".popUpDiv").toggle("fast");
                    //$(this).toggleClass("active");
                    return false;
                });

    $("#closePopsPan").on("click",function(){
        $(".popUpDiv").toggle("fast");
    });
            });
```

Updated jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/Rm3sC/8/

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead

Comment: We were said from jQuery team personally - to forget about `live`. Live was a nice tool till was replaced by `.on()`. Now they're sad that they've lost a nice method name forever.